# JavaScript / jQuery gallery that supports images and swf?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, flash, gallery

I'm looking for a simple JavaScript / jQuery gallery with the following features:

- There should be some thumbs on the page and a large image.
- When a thumb is clicked the large image is replaced with with a large image of the thumb.
- If a particular thumb image is clicked a swf is loaded in place of the large image.
- It would be nice if there was a transition effect when the large image is swapped out when the next thumb is clicked.

I tried to build something, but it was too buggy. I have seen many galleries which support both images and swf files but they open in a lightbox and this is not what I want.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FeaturedContentSlider has the thumbnail functionality you mentioned, and is a jQuery slider that supports swf files (each slide accepts any html content you put in it, even if the demo dosn't illustrate that). Here's the link! http://css-tricks.com/examples/FeaturedContentSlider/

Comment: thanks, i'm going to have a look at all of them and i'll feedback.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Joseph I had a play about with Featured content slider, and was looking at the code and saw that it was built using coda slider:

http://www.ndoherty.biz/demos/coda-slider/2.0/

So I've gone with this solution, it works perfectly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

my friend one of the easiest and the best is pikaChose
Simplest demo fulfilling your needs
[pika chose simple gallery](http://pikachoose.com/demos/tooltip/)

integration with lightbox/fancy box
[fancy box pika chose](http://pikachoose.com/how-to-fancybox/)

Just go through the code once and you wills surely love it

Comment: Hi,

Thanks but I don't think it supports swf files, and also just to clarify I do not need a lightbox.

Thanks